# Need Schema file of 860 EDI File X12, version 4010

Tags: schema, edi, b2b

I am parsing 860 edi file using window application and i validate this file using Fredi component with LoadSchema method means we need the schema file like **860_4010.sef**.

Can anyone please provide the schema file or any way to generate of this ?

Answer (score 3):

SEF files can be somewhat uncommon (for good reason).  I know many partners don't trade them, and will exchange sample files and implementation guides instead.  You should ask your trading partner if they support them.

That being said, here is a link to an automotive company that provides SEF files as a download: http://web.gsec.ford.com/GEC/edispecs/edispecs.asp.  There is an 860 SEF file for a version 3060 download.  You can edit the SEF file to fit your liking, but be warned: it's a jungle.  EDIDev makes a SEF manager found here: http://www.edidev.com/SEF.htm

Comment: Thanks Andrew,i have that 3030 version file already which does not support and giving error on LoadEDI method like :{"[DESCRIPTION:Standard requirement value 'C' not valid in agency 'ASC/X12'.][CODE:13295]" }, i stucked with this error & did n't get any finding on this.

Comment: This link might help you:  it is an implementation guide of SEF files and how they are defined. https://docs.tibco.com/pub/foresight/foresight_common_docs/sef161.pdf  You will have to edit your SEF file.  There's a good reason why people don't trade these documents.  They are nasty to work with.

Comment: Have you contacted EDIDev for support?  Maybe they have a SEF file you can use.